# @angular/cli 6.0 tslint teamcity formatting doesn't work anymore

Tags: angular, tslint, angular-cli-v6

In the previous version of @angular/cli I was simply running: `ng lint --format tslint-teamcity-reporter` but this doesn't work anymore.

Inside the new `angular.json` format I tried creating a new configuration called `teamcity`:

`"lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "teamcity": {
                            "format": "msbuild"
                        }
                    }
                }`

But the output format options don't contain anything related to TeamCity. How can I add the previously used formatter? Thanks

Comment: as a workaround I replaced `ng lint --format tslint-teamcity-reporter`  with `tslint --formatters-dir node_modules/tslint-teamcity-reporter/ --format TSHintTeamcity --project ./`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Angular version 6.1 (just released) custom formatters are enabled again :-)

```
"configurations": {
    "ci": {
      "format": "tslint-teamcity-reporter"
    }
}
```